# Responsive Thumbnail Grid

Tags: html, css, grid, responsive, thumbnails

I am trying to create a responsive grid of thumbnails for a project.
However no matter how I try to tweak it I never end up with quite what I wish for.
I've tried grid/flex/minmax/auto-fit/auto-fill and even old style css to achieve this.

The important part for me is to keep the thumbnail container at 180x300px or similar ratio when responsive. I've seen some websites using this aspect ratio approach to make the thumbnails smaller and closer to each other if the window gets resized.
Not sure how this technique is called therefor I am not able to search for it.
The thumbnails are spanning over the entire with of their parent container, in this case a 100% wide container

Here's some code I am left with at this point in time.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap
}

.container,.entry {
  margin: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 180px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="entry" id="1"></div>
  <div class="entry" id="2"></div>
  <div class="entry" id="3"></div>
  <div class="entry" id="4"></div>
  <div class="entry" id="5"></div>
  <div class="entry" id="6"></div>
  <div class="entry" id="7"></div>
  <div class="entry" id="8"></div>
  <div class="entry" id="9"></div>
  <div class="entry" id="10"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm hoping I am understanding correctly.  This should maintain aspect of 180x300 and create a grid down to 600px breakpoint at which point a media query switches from `grid` to `flex`.

```css
    .container {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      background: black;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      padding: 48px;
      align-items: center;
    }


    @media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {

      .container {
        background: black;
        grid-column: 1 / -1;
        grid-gap: 12px;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(180px, 1fr));
        align-content: space-evenly;

      }
    }

    .entry {
      width: 180px;
      height: 300px;
      /* width: 100%; */
      background: red;
      margin: 6px 12px;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
      .entry {
        width: 180px;
        height: 300px;
        background: blue;
      }
    }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no" />

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="entry" id="1"></div>
    <div class="entry" id="2"></div>
    <div class="entry" id="3"></div>
    <div class="entry" id="4"></div>
    <div class="entry" id="5"></div>
    <div class="entry" id="6"></div>
    <div class="entry" id="7"></div>
    <div class="entry" id="8"></div>
    <div class="entry" id="9"></div>
    <div class="entry" id="10"></div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```